# Resource Not Found Exception on Android devices under 24

Tags: android, data-binding, android-drawable, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

I'm getting the exception when the app is trying to render a drawable with fillType (only supported in API 24+), however in the description of the warning it states that the attribute will just be ignored. This leads me to believe that something strange is happening, since it should still load without the gradients in the drawable (or load something at least).

Since the exception suggests that the cause of the error is that it cannot find a resource, I've double checked to make sure that the references to the drawables being rendered exist. I've checked to make sure that the correct drawableId is being passed and that everything is intact.

Other posts on this site regarding this exception found that their issues were solved after cleaning/syncing/rebuilding/invalidating cache and restarting, however I have done all of the above and it didn't work. I tried on different emulators (Genymotion and Android Emulator), as well as physical devices.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your app gradle file to include

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

And add the [support vector drawable library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#vector) as well

```
implementation  'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
```